# similarity transform with opencv (cv2.estimateRigidTransform) fails unpredictably for 3 point inputs

Tags: python, opencv, affinetransform

I am using opencv '2.4.12'. I get a reasonable result for some inputs but it fails in an unpredictable manner.

```
src = np.array( [(164, 215), (128, 8), (480, 72)] ).reshape(1,-1,2)
dst = np.array( [(175, 237), (146, 44), (486, 99)] ).reshape(1,-1,2)

print cv2.estimateRigidTransform( dst, src, False )

[[  1.03569069e+00 -2.16529654e-03  -2.09931922e+01]
 [  2.16529654e-03   1.03569069e+00  -3.34366192e+01]]
```

This worked ok but if dst is changed slightly to:

```
dst = np.array( [(141, 221), (102, 23), (471, 10)] ).reshape(1,-1,2)

print cv2.estimateRigidTransform( dst, src, False )

None
```

It seems to me that the y coord of 2nd and 3rd inputs need to increase (like 44 - > 99 but not 23 -> 10). Otherwise, the estimated transformation has too much error that no result will be returned from the function, although rotation should be taken care of. I am just guessing why.. But I wouldn't know what is going on here.

Just visually inspecting the inputs, the two cases are not so different. So, I should get a similar transform but with opposite direction of rotation.

Is there a way to get around this limitation? Or, alternative function in opencv for similarity transform (rotation + scale + translation)?

(edit)

Maybe rotation is the most tricky parameter to figure out. I actually could correct for rotation by myself (since I know 2nd and 3rd points define the angle in my case) and let opencv figure out scale and translation. This would not be a general solution though.

(edit 2)
Including one more point (e.i., 4 points) seems to help a lot.

Comment: Are you sure there is actually a rigid transformation that relates the two set of points? Not all triangles are related by a rigid transformation. For e.g. a right triangle and an equilateral triangle are not related by a rigid transformation...only affine. Only similar triangles are related by a rigid transform, and your triangles aren't similar.